# Why I get: '%', '(', <expression>, <input parameter>, '?', FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('?

Tags: java, mysql

I get an error in my Repository in Java Springboot.

In my controller I get the chosen `categorie` from the html page. I want to make a list of `opleiding` that covers the criteria of that `categorie`.

To make that list I call a query: `GeefEenLijstvanCategorie(categorie)`:

```
String categorie = request.getParameter("categorie");
List<Opleiding> list = opleidingRepository.GeefEenLijstvanCategorie(categorie);
```

But I get an error in the Repository. The repository and queries in My Sql is all very new to me.

In the repository I have:

```
@Query("select o from Opleiding o where o.thema LIKE (String categorie)")
List<Opleiding> GeefEenLijstvanCategorie(String categorie);
```

This error occurs, positioned between the `LIKE` and `(String categorie)`:

> `%', '(', <expression>, <input parameter>, '?', FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('`

Comment: INVALID SQL: `select o from Opleiding o where o.thema LIKE (String categorie)`.  BETTER: `select o from Opleiding o where o.thema LIKE '%categorie%'`  SUGGESTION: Learn about [prepared statements](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-select-like/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:` to use the value of a parameter.

```
@Query("select o from Opleiding o where o.thema LIKE '%:categorie%'")
```

Comment: thankyou for helping me on the right track. At the end the following solution did it for me:
@Query("select o from Opleiding o where o.thema = :categorie")